# Setting different intervals for React component render

Tags: reactjs, setinterval

I want to sync two elements in a component. One of the elements is an image gallery, that needs to rotate images. However, due to the rendering time of the other element, I need to render images differently each time. I have managed to write the logic below, but so far it doesn't work, and the first interval is always used.

**Intervals:**

```
export const imageRotationSpeed = {
  1: 5800,
  2: 3500,
  3: 4500,
  4: 3700,
};
```

**Component code part:** The dictionary above is imported, and I'm referring to the interval value as `imageRotationSpeed[i]`

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      imageId: 1,
      rotationSpeedId: 1,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.timeout = setInterval(() => {
      let currentIdx = this.state.imageId;
      if (this.state.imageId != 4) {
        this.setState({
          imageId: currentIdx + 1,
          rotationSpeedId: this.state.rotationSpeedId + 1,
        });
      } else if (this.state.imageId == 4) {
        this.setState({ imageId: 1, rotationSpeedId: 1 });
      }
    }, imageRotationSpeed[this.state.rotationSpeedId]); //this always is the first value of 5800
  }

  componentDidUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.timeout);
  }
```

What would be a better way to achieve the rotating set of intervals with different values?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var intervalTimes = [1000,2000,3500,2500];

var imageId = 1;

console.log(imageId+".jpg");

setTimeout(function(){
  setImageId();
}, intervalTimes[0]);

function setImageId(){
  var current = imageId;
  imageId = (current % 4) + 1, // +1 for image file naming
  console.log(imageId+".jpg");
  setTimeout(function(){
    setImageId();
  }, intervalTimes[((current+1) % 4)]);
}
```

I only thought about calling a function in a different time interval for each. But if you want to images to stay same time on screen. I think you should use an eventlistener for image load and then set an timeout for change image in it. Because images load time can change.

```
constructor(props) {


super(props);
  this.state = {
    imageId: 1,
  };
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.timeout = setTimeout(this.setImageId, imageRotationSpeed[0]);
}

componentDidUnmount() {
  clearInterval(this.timeout);
}

setImageId = () => {
  let currentIdx = this.state.imageId;
  this.setState({
      imageId: (currentIdx % 4) + 1, // +1 for image file naming
  });
  this.timeout = setTimeout(this.setImageId, imageRotationSpeed[((currentIdx) % 4)]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm running into 0.jpg issue. The thing is, that images are numerated 1.jpg, 2.jpg, etc. 1-4. and at some point your code produces 0, and there is no 0.jpg

Comment: you can add 1 to imageId while setting state. I edited the answer

Comment: Still, starts from the second image (2.jpg), and goes crazy when reaches the 4-th. Seems  doesn't reset to loop.

Comment: Im sorry i forgot to change setInterval to setTimeout. Now i edited the answer and add an small preview snippet

Comment: Thanks a lot, but the whole thing is that I need that 1000 to be dynamic, that's why I made the different rotation speed dictionary. You can see the needed values. I.e. the second image needs to render after 5.8 seconds, the third after 3.5 second, etc.

Comment: Are you serious? You are just want us to write your all code here. It was just an preview to show file naming is okay

Comment: Dude, the code I pasted in the question was already doing the rotation with a fixed interval, good or bad. My question was in making it dynamic, which I clearly stated, having different values all the time. I see you've added the dynamic intervals, I'll try now, and if I make it work you'll earn the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do recursive coding in componentDidMount(). It loads once. That's why the interval is always the first one- setInterval is loaded only once. Put those conditionals in the fetch() or whatever api call you are using. And if you only have those four options just hard code them to get it to work. I don't support making them a dictionary, but that's just preference (it might even be a little unnecessary to put them in state).

Some pseudo-code:

```
componentDidMount() {
  fetch('http://images.io')
    .then(function(data){
      let rotation;
      data.images.map(image => {
        if(data.imageId == 1) {
          rotation = 5800;
          return image.rotation;
        } else if (data.imageId == 2) {
          rotation = 3500;
          return image.rotation;
        } else if (data.imageId == 3) {
          rotation = 4500;
          return image.rotation;
        } else if )data.imageId == 4) {
          rotation = 3700;
          return image.rotation;
        }
      });
    })
    .catch(err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
}
```

This isn't a complete answer, but this is how you have to think about the data flow.

If I were you, I'd start from scratch and remove the setTimeOut or setInterval. I'd set a closure variable to the imageRotationSpeed needed based on a conditional like the one above. Then where ever you are using the rotationSpeed, plug in that variable.

If it is based on the order of the images coming in and not object property data that you can access off the data in the fetch return, then set another variable to that order. Usually you use a counter loop to record intervals:

```
this.state = {
currentIdx: []
position: 0;
};


forEach.currentIdx(this.setState({position: this.state.position++;})
```

Depends on how you set up the code. That could go in a reducer, but don't worry about Redux here. The easiest way is to increment the position inside a fetch .then().

Sorry this is not a complete answer, but hopefully it gave you some ideas and a clearer understanding.

SPECIAL NOTE: These exact types of problems are why I am upset with React for not replacing UNSAFE_componentWillMount() with an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.timeout = setInterval(() => {
      let currentIdx = this.state.imageId;
      if (this.state.imageId != 4) {
        this.setState({
          imageId: currentIdx + 1,
        });
      } else if (this.state.imageId == 4) {
        this.setState({ imageId: 1 });
      }
    }, imageRotationSpeed[this.state.imageId]);
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (prevState.imageId !== this.state.imageId) {
      clearInterval(this.timeout);
      this.timeout = setInterval(() => {
        let currentIdx = this.state.imageId;
        if (this.state.imageId != 4) {
          this.setState({
            imageId: currentIdx + 1,
          });
        } else if (this.state.imageId == 4) {
          this.setState({ imageId: 1 });
        }
      }, imageRotationSpeed[this.state.imageId]);
    }
  }

  componentDidUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.timeout);
  }
```

Turned out I needed to add `componentDidUpdate()` to make everything work!
Thanks to [This link](https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/)